# How do you test a textField isn’t empty before passing it to a function:

Tags: swift, option-type, conditional-operator

I have a textfield that accepts numbers.
When tapping outside the area of the number pad to dismiss the keyboard it passes the text field value to a function.

When the text field is empty I get the NIL unpacked optional error and it crashes.

I am trying to find a way to pass a "0" to the variable when the text field has nothing in it.

The variable

```
@IBOUTLET weak var per1kCollector: UITextField?
var per1k = 0
```

The handler to close the keyboard and call the function
per1k grabs the textfield
per1k needs a 0 if collector.text is NIL

```
@objc func handleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("closing number pad")
    
            view.endEditing(true)
            per1k = (Int(per1kCollector!.text!)! ?? 0)

            doSomeMath()
    
}
```

This keeps stating "cannot convert value of type 'int' to expected argument type 'string'.    But, I'm taking the Int of the text field, and per1k IS type int.  ????

Comment: Any time your code says `!` you should _expect_ to crash. Try to avoid it. There's very little need for it.

Comment: Also do not type your "code" into the question. Copy and paste _real_ code. Nonsense like `@IBOUTLET` is unnecessary.

Comment: not sure I follow you.  Everywhere else when I see screen shots folks are recommended to cut and paste, which is what I did.

Comment: No you didn't, because there is no such thing as `@IBOUTLET`. Your code would never have compiled if you said that. You'd get an error, "Unknown attribute 'IBOUTLET'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time your code says `!` you should *expect* to crash. Try to avoid it. There's very little need for it. In this case just use a question mark:

```
 per1k = Int(per1kCollector?.text ?? "0") ?? 0
```

Comment: every time I don't I keep getting the darn options to fix it that way... believe me I'm trying

Comment: Matt, thanks for helping here.  I'm still getting the error that I can't convert Int to expected argument String.   I'm not sure what String it's referring to.  the textField value is being handled with Int() and the variable there was init'd as an Int.

Comment: OK fixed, sorry about that.